# Find number of terms in arithmetic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions

In a arithmetic progression sum of first four terms sum :
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=124$$

and sum of last four terms :
$$a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}=156$$
and sum of arithmetic progression is :
$$S_n=350$$

$$n=?$$

How to find $n$? I tried using arithmetic progression sum formulas but getting negative or fractional numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}+a_n=280$. The mean of those
eight terms is $35$, so the mean of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is also $35$. The sum
of those $n$ terms is $n$ times their mean, and is $350$. So now you can read
off $n$.

Comment: hohohoh man thank you a lot. God bless you

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$$ where $$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=d$$

Answer (score 0):

$$350=\dfrac{n(a_1+a_n)}2$$

Now $a_1+a_n=a_2+a_{n-1}=\cdots=\dfrac{124+156}4$

Answer (score 0):

Use standard formula of A.P.
which is

$a_n = a + (n-1)d$

and a simple difference formula

$a_n - a_{n-1} = d$